# Motion Tracking + MatchMoving -- What am I doing wrong?

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh, tracking

I'm trying to track the camera in this piece of footage and then also track the object on the stick (to replace the object with a 3D object and remove the pole).

I am a newbie, but I think I got the trackers to a low solve ERROR, so it should be working right --- I also plugged in my camera lens (35mm) and my sensor size, (Fujifilm T3 -- I looked up it was 28mm but maybe I read it wrong).

The results are horrible -- with the camera shaking hysterically. I do not know what is happening but this happens often when I try to motion track and match-move this kind of footage.

Can anyone help this idiot? lol. If you want to contact me privately, I will tip you a little bit for your time.

Here is a link to the videos that illustrate what the camera track is looking like: https://f.io/smQOQvPd

Picture with specs here:  https://f.io/gX-H3BrI

Answer (score 2):

If the camera is static you need a different kind of solver then the default. Use tripod solver for the camera, and exclude the trackers for the object in the camera solution. 
Then track again the object only, and solve the object separately.